# Check userid if exists in table then update else insert in mysql version 5.7.15

Tags: mysql, database

So i want to implement an UPSERT query. Where i do not wish to query and first check if the user exists and then insert rather i want to check during insertion and update the field if the user exists. I have tried all these queries but none work.

```
INSERT INTO `sys_cart` (`userid`, `product_ids`, `date_added`, `date_updated`, `date_deleted`)
VALUES (2 ,`3,4`, `2017-02-01 00:00:00`, `2017-02-01 00:00:00`, null)
ON DUPLICATE `sys_cart.userid` UPDATE `product_ids` = '12,13';

INSERT INTO 'sys_cart'
VALUES (4, '34,12', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', null)
ON DUPLICATE userid UPDATE product_ids = VALUES('3,4');

INSERT INTO 'sys_cart'
VALUES (4, 'Gorilla', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', null)
ON DUPLICATE userid UPDATE product_ids;

INSERT INTO 'sys_cart'
VALUES (4, 'Gorilla', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', null)
ON DUPLICATE userid UPDATE product_ids = VALUES('3,4');

INSERT INTO sys_cart (userid, product_ids, date_added, date_updated, date_deleted)
VALUES (4, "Gorilla", "2017-02-01 00:00:00", "2017-02-01 00:00:00", null)
ON DUPLICATE userid UPDATE product_ids = VALUES("3,4");

INSERT INTO sys_cart (userid, product_ids, date_added, date_updated, date_deleted)
VALUES (4, "Gorilla", "2017-02-01 00:00:00", "2017-02-01 00:00:00", null)
ON DUPLICATE userid UPDATE product_ids = "3,4";
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Don't put comma-separated values in a table column. Use a separate many-to-many relationship table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), the syntax is `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, literally. You can't specify *which* column is the key in the query - that's defined at the table level.

You syntax should be:

```
INSERT INTO sys_cart 
VALUES (4, '34,12', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', '2017-02-01 00:00:00', null)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_ids = VALUES(product_ids)
```

What you may also be missing is that `userid` must be defined as the `PRIMARY KEY` of `sys_cart`. You may need to do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE sys_cart 
MODIFY COLUMN userid INT PRIMARY KEY
```

---

As an aside, you should consider using a child table for the product ids, rather than stuffing a CSV into a single field, which will be hard to deal with later on.

Comment: It throws an  error "Unrecognized keyword (Near KEY)". I have set userid as the primary key. The primary key is also an INT and set to auto increment.

Comment: @AbhijeetChakravorty I don't understand why you would be getting an error. This syntax is plainly in the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Hurrayy!!! After i deleted the id key and reset the userid as primary key it worked. Thankss a tonn!!! @Bohemian